# How to setup the terrafrom Backend configuration using init Command

Tags: terraform

How to setup the terraform Backend configuration using CLI arguments using Terraform init Command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever a configuration's backend changes you must run the terraform init to again validate and configure the backend before you can perform any plans and operations.

The [Terraform init [options]](https://www.terraform.io/docs/cli/commands/init.html)  performs several different initialization steps.After Initialization you can perform other commands.

for [backend configuration](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/settings/backends/configuration.html) you need to define a conffiguration file specified in init command.

init setting is defined in this way:

```
$ terraform init \
        -backend-config="address=demo.consul.io" \
        -backend-config="path=example_app/terraform_state" \
        -backend-config="scheme=https"
```